# SageMaker endpoint can't load huggingface tokenizer

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I used Amazon SageMaker to train a HuggingFace model. At the end of the training script provided to the estimator, I saved the model into the correct path (`SM_MODEL_DIR`):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--model-dir", type=str, default=os.environ["SM_MODEL_DIR"])
    
    ...
    
    trainer.model.save_pretrained(args.model_dir)
```

After the model was trained, I deployed it using the `deploy` method of the HuggingFace estimator. Once the endpoint was successfully created, I tried inference with the returned predictor:

```
response = self.predictor.predict(
    {"inputs": "I want to know where is my order"}
)
```

And I received the following client error:

```
{'code': 400, 'type': 'InternalServerException', 'message': "Can't load tokenizer for '/.sagemaker/mms/models/model'. Make sure that:\n\n- '/.sagemaker/mms/models/model' is a correct model identifier listed on 'https://huggingface.co/models'\n\n- or '/.sagemaker/mms/models/model' is the correct path to a directory containing relevant tokenizer files\n\n"}
```

Why cannot the tokenizer be loaded?

Comment: Facing the same issue for essentially the same environmental setting. Were you able to figure out the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the `trainer.model.save_pretrained(args.model_dir)` line above, you are only exporting the model.

If you want to ensure that the tokenizer (config) is saved, you ought to use `trainer.save_model()` instead. This would ensure both the model and the tokenizer are exported, as long as you pass in the tokenizer when instantiating the `Trainer`.